Как сделать одинаковую высоту футеров карточек, если содержимое контейнера меняется?

Из-за разного объёма текста, нижние содержимые карточек находятся на разной высоте. Как сделать так, чтобы эти содержимые находились на одной высоте? (как показано на 2-й картинке)



.journal-section {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.journal-collections {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.journal-collections-item {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 310px);
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    column-gap: 50px;
    row-gap: 50px;
}

.card {
    display: inline-block;
    border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 2px solid;
    max-width: 310px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card-desc {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;

}

.card-tag {
    font-size: 16px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.card-title {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.card-title:hover {
    color: #2282FF;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.card-describe {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.card-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-flow: row;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26px;
}

.card-footer-left, .card-footer-right {
    display: flex;
}

.card-footer-btn {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
                <div class="journal-section">
                    <div class="journal-collections">
                        <div class="journal-collections-item">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img">
                                    <a href="#!"><img src="/journal/img-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-desc">
                                    <div class="card-tag">Журнал &#183; Интересные статьи</div>
                                    <a href="#!" class="card-title">Еда-2025</a>
                                    <p class="card-describe">Казалось бы, только недавно все писали о трендах-2024, а вот уже настала пора перелистывать календарь.</p>
                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <div class="card-footer-left">
                                            <div class="card-footer-views">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>&nbsp; 21  &nbsp; &#183;  &nbsp; 29 окт.</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer-right">
                                            <div class="card-footer-repost">
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-share card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer-likes">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img">
                                    <a href="#!"><img src="/journal/img-2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-desc">
                                    <div class="card-tag">Журнал &#183; Статьи</div>
                                    <a href="#!" class="card-title">Сегодня готовим борщ по традиционному рецепту</a>
                                    <p class="card-describe">Хорошему борщу не нужны ни сало, ни чеснок, ни пампушки... Только сметана!</p>
                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <div class="card-footer-left">
                                            <div class="card-footer-views">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>&nbsp; 55  &nbsp; &#183;  &nbsp; 28 окт.</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer-right">
                                            <div class="card-footer-repost">
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-share card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer-likes">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img">
                                    <a href="#!"><img src="/journal/img-3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-desc">
                                    <div class="card-tag">Журнал &#183; Дайджест</div>
                                    <a href="#!" class="card-title">5 новых рецептов от шефов «Boemi»</a>
                                    <p class="card-describe">Осень – время уюта и тепла. И это касается не только погоды в доме и за его пределами, но и еды.</p>
                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <div class="card-footer-left">
                                            <div class="card-footer-views">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>&nbsp; 117  &nbsp; &#183;  &nbsp; 28 окт.</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer-right">
                                            <div class="card-footer-repost">
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-share card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer-likes">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>




Для .card-footer не margin-bottom: auto а margin-top: auto

Попробуйте card-footer убрать из области вложения card-desc и вывести на один с ним уровень (card-desc)

Нужно обернуть элементы в два объекта(в данном примере top и bottom) и с помощью justify-content расставить по разным сторонам


.journal-section {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.journal-collections {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.journal-collections-item {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 10px;
}

.card {
    display: block;
    // border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 2px solid;
    max-width: 310px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-desc {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 2px solid;
}

.card-tag {
    font-size: 16px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.card-title {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.card-title:hover {
    color: #2282FF;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.card-describe {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.card-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-flow: row;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 26px;
}

.card-footer-left, .card-footer-right {
    display: flex;
}

.card-footer-btn {
    opacity: 0.3;
}
<div class="journal-section">
                    <div class="journal-collections">
                        <div class="journal-collections-item">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img">
                                    <a href="#!"><img src="/journal/img-1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-desc">
                                    <div class="top">
                                      <div class="card-tag">Журнал &#183; Интересные статьи</div>
                                    <a href="#!" class="card-title">Еда-2025</a>
                                    <p class="card-describe">Казалось бы, только недавно все писали о трендах-2024, а вот уже настала пора перелистывать календарь.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                      <div class="card-footer">
                                        <div class="card-footer-left">
                                            <div class="card-footer-views">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>&nbsp; 21  &nbsp; &#183;  &nbsp; 29 окт.</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer-right">
                                            <div class="card-footer-repost">
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-share card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer-likes">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img">
                                    <a href="#!"><img src="/journal/img-2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-desc">
                                    <div class="top">
                                    <div class="card-tag">Журнал &#183; Статьи</div>
                                    <a href="#!" class="card-title">Сегодня готовим борщ по традиционному рецепту</a>
                                    <p class="card-describe">Хорошему борщу не нужны ни сало, ни чеснок, ни пампушки... Только сметана!</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                      <div class="card-footer">
                                        <div class="card-footer-left">
                                            <div class="card-footer-views">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>&nbsp; 55  &nbsp; &#183;  &nbsp; 28 окт.</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer-right">
                                            <div class="card-footer-repost">
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-share card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer-likes">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-img">
                                    <a href="#!"><img src="/journal/img-3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-desc">
                                    <div class="top">
                                      <div class="card-tag">Журнал &#183; Дайджест</div>
                                    <a href="#!" class="card-title">5 новых рецептов от шефов «Boemi»</a>
                                    <p class="card-describe">Осень – время уюта и тепла. И это касается не только погоды в доме и за его пределами, но и еды.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="bottom">
                                      <div class="card-footer">
                                        <div class="card-footer-left">
                                            <div class="card-footer-views">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 15px;"><i class="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>&nbsp; 117  &nbsp; &#183;  &nbsp; 28 окт.</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer-right">
                                            <div class="card-footer-repost">
                                                <i class="fa-solid fa-share card-footer-btn" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-footer-likes">
                                                <button class="card-footer-btn"><i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i></button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



